# Erlang read from file the first 5 rows

Tags: file, file-io, erlang

For example i have txt file with 10 string of text. How can i read first 5 string of this text with erlang?

Thank you.

Comment: @OP: You are requested to accept an answer, if any of the answer posted answers your question and you are satisfied with it.

Comment: @ArunMu: A user will see the comment, added to his (her) post, even if there's no `@` in front of the nick. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably you want a combination of [`file:open/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#open-2) and [`file:read_line/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#read_line-1) with buffering enabled.

A rhyme:

```
$ cat mary_lamb.txt
Mary had a little lamb,
little lamb, little lamb,
Mary had a little lamb,
whose fleece was white as snow.
And everywhere that Mary went,
Mary went, Mary went,
and everywhere that Mary went,
the lamb was sure to go.
```

Source file:

```
$ cat ./read_n_lines.erl
-module(read_n_lines).
-export([read_n_lines/2]).

read_n_lines(Filename,NumLines) ->
     {ok, FileDev} = file:open(Filename, 
          [raw, read, read_ahead]),
     Lines = do_read([],FileDev, NumLines),
     file:close(FileDev),
     Lines.

do_read(Lines, _, 0) ->
     lists:reverse(Lines);
do_read(Lines, FileDev, L) ->
     case file:read_line(FileDev) of
          {ok, Line} ->
               do_read([Line|Lines], FileDev, L - 1);
          eof ->
               do_read(Lines, FileDev, 0)
     end.
```

`raw`, in `Modes`, passed to the `file:open/2`, allows faster access to a file, because no Erlang process is needed to handle the file.

Sample run:

```
$ erl
1> c(read_n_lines).
{ok,read_n_lines}
2> Lines = read_n_lines:read_n_lines("./mary_lamb.txt", 5).
["Mary had a little lamb,\n","little lamb, little lamb,\n",
 "Mary had a little lamb,\n",
 "whose fleece was white as snow.\n",
 "And everywhere that Mary went,\n"]
3> length(Lines).
5
4> read_n_lines:read_n_lines("./mary_lamb.txt", 666).
["Mary had a little lamb,\n","little lamb, little lamb,\n",
 "Mary had a little lamb,\n",
 "whose fleece was white as snow.\n",
 "And everywhere that Mary went,\n",
 "Mary went, Mary went,\n",
 "and everywhere that Mary went,\n",
 "the lamb was sure to go."]
5>
```

To remove newline from a string, you can use [`string:strip/1,2,3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#strip-1):

```
5> lists:map(fun(X) -> string:strip(X, right, $\n) end, Lines).
["Mary had a little lamb,","little lamb, little lamb,",
 "Mary had a little lamb,",
 "whose fleece was white as snow.",
 "And everywhere that Mary went,"]
6>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, n_times can be used elsewhere:

```
-module(n_times).

-export([test/0]).

test() ->
  io:format("~p~n", [n_lines("n_times.erl", 5)]).

n_lines(FileName, N) ->
  {ok, FileDev} = file:open(FileName, [raw, read, read_ahead]),
  try
    n_times(fun() -> {ok, L} = file:read_line(FileDev), L end, N)
  after
    file:close(FileDev)
  end.

n_times(F, N) ->
  n_times(F, N, []).

n_times(_, 0, A) ->
  lists:reverse(A);
n_times(F, N, A) ->
  n_times(F, N-1, [F()|A]).
```

Answer (score 1):

use io module of erlang.

io:read(FD,'').

Where FD is the File handle.

Also please do lookup the erlang doc for the correct syntax.

Here is a rough code

```
func(FD) ->
case io:get_line(FD,'') of
{ok,text}->
 %%do something,
func(FD);
eof ->
%%exit;
error->
%%quit
end
```

You can use a counter if you want to process just 10 lines

Comment: I see you have mentioned string or is it lines you have intended to say ?? If it is string..then read the first line and tokenize it using the string module of erlang.... or use bit operations classic functional programming style :)

Comment: This reads terms, not strings :-) "Reads a term `Term` from the standard input (`IoDevice`), prompting it with `Prompt`."